# How to change ports in UniserverZ and/or Uniserv?

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, webserver

I'm asking this because every single time i need to update the program, the configuration file is updated too and the port must need rechanged, but my question is honest because:

1) When i try to use what appears in the documentation it doesn't work

2) When i go to the forums asking for help, they send me to the documentation...

3) When i go to the irc, they told me how to do it, but there is just one guy there and sometimes he never answer your questions

So, taking all of that in consideration, i guess the best is write a question and (hopefully) wait for someone to know how to do it.

Else, of course, if i found how to do it, i'm gonna come back and answer the question too, so i have a place where to consult and the other people who use this program (already have years of existance) also have a fast way to consult that.

Any question, suggestion or comment leading to find this 'how' would be much apreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you already tried this ? http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/Coral:_general_change_ports. What is the error message you are getting from logs ?

Comment: I can't open the graphic interphase because of the ports problem, and also the modification of the files, directly, doesn't work, like i said before, i check the documentation of the program before, thanks in any case, any other ideas? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the documentation it suggest than you can edit through guy the port server, but the thing is it doesn't let you enter the GUI because the port is already in use

The way to circunvent this is to start windows in safe mode and then open UniServer, this way the guy opens in any case because there is a huge chance than the program is using the port will be deactive in that moment too, so after start with safe mode (with or without internet) you can go to apache tab and change ports.

There is a way to do it through editing some documents with notepad than i used to use before, but i couln't find the way now anyway, if somebody know it, please let me know in one separated answer, you never can have enough good answers to a problem. ;)